# Successful call to onAnimationUpdate, but no change in display using ValueAnimator within View::onDraw

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I am trying to animate a circle's opacity in the `OnDraw` function of a class extending `View` using `ValueAnimator` w/`setAlpha`. I've put a debugging Toast inside `onAnimationUpdate`. A rapid succession of toast bubbles show the alpha values (onAnimatetionUpdate is hit and has the correct values), but the shape does not change on the screen. I have tried `invalidate()` and `postInvalidate()` within `onAnimationUpdate()` but think it's a red herring.

From https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation

> Depending on what property or object you are animating,
>   you might need to call the invalidate() ...
>   setAlpha() and setTranslationX() invalidate the View properly,
>   so you do not need to invalidate the View when calling these methods with new values.

Example code might look like:

```
    Paint CircleFill_dah = new Paint(); // hit of dah duration
    CircleFill_dah.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    ValueAnimator animator_dah = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0,255);

    CircleFill_dah.setColor(dahColor);
    CircleFill_dah.setAlpha(0);
    animator_dah.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            int alphval = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            CircleFill_dah.setAlpha(alphval);
            //we are here but are not redrawing!?
            Toast.makeText(c,"setting alpha " + alphval,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //view.postInvalidate(); // clears toast messages, but doesn't show animation
        }
    });
    canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 50, CircleFill_dah);
    animator_dah.setDuration(100);
    animator_dah.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
    animator_dah.setRepeatCount(-1);
    animator_dah.start();
```

The actual code is [on github](https://github.com/WillForan/DitDahRing/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/chris/dit_dah_ring/Touchable.java#L305). `clearView extends View` and implements `onDraw`, calling `Touchable.draw()` which uses `Touchable.fill()`

Comment: you have to `View#invalidate` inside `onAnimationUpdate` and call `drawCircle` inside `onDraw` with the given `Paint`

Comment: I have `postInvalidate()` commented out in the example, but have tried that and `invalidate()` to no avail. (Thanks for the quick comment!)

Comment: ok, what is `canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 50, CircleFill_dah);` doing here? its not `onDraw` method, is it? and make reasonable duration - 100 ms is much shorter than a [blink of your eye](https://www.quora.com/How-long-does-one-take-to-blink)

Comment: Good point on the timer, 1000ms is much easier to debug. 100ms is a lot of time for the human brain. We can describe scenes [given half that time](https://www.livescience.com/42666-human-brain-sees-images-record-speed.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the animation's `start()` should not be in the in `onDraw()`!

`invalidate()` also appears to be necessary.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View v = new TestView(this);
        setContentView(v);
    }

    private static class TestView extends View {
        Paint CircleFill_dah = new Paint(); // hit of dah duration
        ValueAnimator animator_dah = ValueAnimator.ofInt(100,255);

        public TestView (Context context) {
            super(context);
            setFocusable(true);

            CircleFill_dah.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

            CircleFill_dah.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            CircleFill_dah.setAlpha(50);
            animator_dah.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    int alphval = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                    CircleFill_dah.setAlpha(alphval);
                    invalidate();
                }
            });

            animator_dah.setDuration(100);
            animator_dah.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
            animator_dah.setRepeatCount(-1);
            animator_dah.start();

        }
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 50, CircleFill_dah);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: still, you have `animator_dah.start();` inside `onDraw()` method - all you need there is `canvas.drawCircle` (and other painting stuff)